# Highlight textbox when clicked blue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok so some websites like twitter etc when you click on the textbot to login it is highlighted blue. How do i do this?

Answer (score 4):

Well if it is twitter, you can have a look at the bootstrap.css code. I think the following css would do the trick (took it out from bootstrap.css):

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

}
```

Reference:

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

Relevant bits of css from Twitter

```
textarea {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
}

textarea:focus {
    border-color: #56B4EF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah26/K9bKD/1/). You can change the color by replacing #56B4EF

```
 input:focus {
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #56B4EF;
 border-color: #56B4EF;
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply CSS to textbox like `border-color:blue;` on `click` or `focus` event.

Comment: Why JavaScript and not pure CSS?